# Show that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x = 0$...

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

We have $f(x) = $

\begin{cases} 
      x\sin(\frac{1}{x}) & x \neq0 \\ 
      0 &  x = 0 
   \end{cases}

My proof is as follows:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Choose $\delta = \epsilon$. $\forall \,0 < |x| < \delta$, we have:

$|f(x) - f(0)| = \Bigl|x\sin(\frac{1}{x}) - 0\Bigr| = \Bigl|x\sin(\frac{1}{x})\Bigr|$

Now, $|\sin\alpha| \leq 1$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, so:

$\Bigl|x\sin(\frac{1}{x})\Bigr| = |x|\,\Bigl|\sin(\frac{1}{x})\Bigr| \leq |x| < \delta = \epsilon$

QED.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Perfectly correct.

Comment: Correct **so far** but I think you need to finish it.  You need to state that what you have done so far shows that $\lim_{x\to 0} x sin(1/x)= 0$ and then that, since f(0)= 0, $\lim_{x\to 0} x sin(1/x)= f(0)$ so that f is continuous at x= 0.

Comment: @user247327 No, what the OP does is show that given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x|<\delta$, which by definition means $f$ is continuous at zero. This is a perfectly good proof.

Comment: @user247327. I don't think that needs to be stated because the first line  includes the (correct) assertion that $|f(x)-f(0)|=|f(x)|$.